# Peek Value in Next Column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql sample **view** table like this

```
  ID     Starttime   Endtime
   1         19
   2         38
   3         90
```

is it possible to peek the next starttime value from the next column and substract 1 so it should be the endtime of the previous ? To be like this :

```
ID     Starttime   Endtime
1         19          37
2         38          89
3         90          ....
```

I need to know if it can be done using mysql query:

*Please note that this is just a view not an actual table.*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a1d2/2

you can use a self join, for example

```
select t1.id, t1.start_time, t2.start_time -1  end_time
from times t1 join times t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1
```

**EDIT**

for where start time is same as end time

```
select t1.id, t1.start_time, greatest(t1.start_time,t2.start_time-1)  end_time
from times_v t1 join times_v t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340897/1

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much. It works as expected but i have a small issue :( There are cases where if the starttime of the previous is the same with that of the present then the endtime is smaller than the starttime for example it will become 30 -> 29 if the next starttime was 30. Is there any condition i could add not to subtract under such circumstances ? Thanks

Comment: @IanKenney life saver !! Thank you a million ! :) :)